# How to define a constraint in OptaPy for a list of element

Tags: python, optapy

I have some difficult to create one of my constraint. The structure of my problem is something like this

```
class ToolFact:
    id : str
    type : str
    
@planning_entity
class SubObjectFact:
    id : str
    tool : ToolFact

@planning_entity
class ObjectFact:
    id : str
    sub_objects : list[SubObjectFact]
```

And I want a constraint that will do something like this

```
for each ObjectFact -> object
   for each SubOjectFact in object.sub_object -> sub_object 
       penalize if sub_object.tool is None
```

But I can't find a way to do this with the constraint_factory.
Does anyone know how please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it with constraint streams:

```
from java.util import ArrayList

def penalize_subs_without_tools(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return constraint_factory.forEach(get_class(ObjectFact)) \
        .flattenLast(lambda fact: ArrayList(fact.sub_objects)) \
        .filter(lambda sub_object: sub_object.tool is None) \
        .penalize("SubObjectFact without tool", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```

I will try to make it so the ArrayList is not necessary in a later version.

Comment: Oh thanks ! That was exaclty what I need. Did you have like a list with a lot of example of constraint like this ? It could be really usefull !!

Comment: OptaPy quickstarts can be found in https://github.com/optapy/optapy-quickstarts, which shows how to apply OptaPy to particular problems. More quickstarts are in OptaPlanner quickstarts https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts, they are in Java, but it easy to map from Java constraint streams to Python constraint streams (they are basically one-to-one). The constraint streams building blocks (including flattenLast) are explained in the docs: https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsIntroduction